# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser: Extract entire DOM tree

Tags: php, html, html-parsing

How can I use the SimpleHTMLDOM Parser to get the entire DOM tree snapshot? Any pointers would help.

Comment: What do you mean by snapshot? A snapshot of the DOM tree in what representation?

Comment: In an array or a string. The idea is to be able to diff it with future changes to content.

Answer (score 0):

once yon constructed the simpledom object is **is** an entire "tree" snapshot? what do you expect? somethin like: `<html><head></head><body><div><p><h1></.....` ? or the extracted plaintext from the website?